# SVN Merge "Range of Revisions" overwrites files in branch

Tags: visual-studio, svn, version-control, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn

I have set up the following working tree using svn:

```
__ Solution
 |__ trunk
     |__ ConsoleApp1

 |__ branches
     |__ Branch1
        |__ ConsoleApp1
```

Now, I've done some work in `Branch1` (which is obviously a branch of `trunk`), at the same time that `trunk` was changed by another person. I want to get these changes into my `Branch1`, so I right-clicked on it, went to Subversion > Merge Project and selected "Merge a range of revisions". The merging went OK, files that were create in `trunk` are now in my branch, and files that I create in `Branch1` are still where they should.

However, some files that I changed and that were also changed in `trunk` were overwritten. I've done a number of attempts and it seems that's the way it works.

Is there any way to keep code from both devlines for the same file, similar to the conflict-solving feature (like TortoiseMerge) for instance? If not, should I try Git or TFS?

**Update:** I tried doing the same, but using TortoiseSVN instead of the AnkhSvn plugin. Works just fine (I get the "conflict" state and the option to open the "Merge Tool". But AnkhSvn just rewrites my file. Any way to overcome this fact?

Comment: I briefly used AnkhSvn and found it had a tendency to translate my actions on files into version control operations I did not intend. I would just stick with Tortoise. (Also, colleagues using AnkhSvn tended to commit files one at a time, rather than in coherent groups, but maybe that was because they were used to CMS on VMS, which worked like that.)

Comment: Try VisualSVN plug-in and report this to AnkhSVN dev team.